# How can I delete a couple of lines of info from a file and keep the rest?

Tags: c++

I am making a banking program that reads from a file where the layout is (account number, SSN, name, address, phone number) I want to be able to delete a user and all of that information from the file but keep all the other accounts.

```cpp
// clientAccount = user-inputted id Number of account to delete
void deleteUser(int& accIndex, string & clientAccount)
{
    
    string  accountNumT[TOTAL_ACCOUNTS],
        userSSNT[TOTAL_ACCOUNTS], clientNameT[TOTAL_ACCOUNTS],
        userAddressT[TOTAL_ACCOUNTS], phoneNumberT[TOTAL_ACCOUNTS];
    ifstream fin(ACCOUNTS_FILE); 
    ofstream fout(ACCOUNTS_FILE);
    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_ACCOUNTS; i++) 
    {
        getline(fin, accountNumT[i]);
        getline(fin, userSSNT[i]);
        getline(fin, clientNameT[i]);
        getline(fin, userAddressT[i]);
        getline(fin, phoneNumberT[i]);
        if (clientAccount == accountNumT[i]) 
        {
            accountNumT[i] = " ";
            userSSNT[i] = " "; 
            clientNameT[i] = " ";
            userAddressT[i] = " ";
            phoneNumberT[i] = " ";
        }
        fout << accountNumT[i] << endl; 
        fout << userSSNT[i] << endl;
        fout << clientNameT[i] << endl;
        fout << userAddressT[i] << endl;
        fout << phoneNumberT[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

I expected the code to iterate through, grab the selected account and replace all the info with " ".
As of now it doesn't do anything

Comment: (1) Read file into a `std::vector` of records (`struct` for a user/account). (2) Remove unwanted records from the vector. (3) Write the vector of records back to file.

Comment: Alternatively, create a second file.   Read all content from the input file before the lines that you want to remove, and write them to the second file.  Read the content you want to remove, but don't write it.  Then read the rest of the input file, and write it to the output file.  Close both files.  Either rename the input file, or (if you don't need to keep it) delete it.  Rename the second file to the original name.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove lines, what you can do is read the whole file (into a `std::vector` or similar), remove the parts you don't want, and write it back to the file.